# return statement is missing error in array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

i'm trying to get elements of an array based on a simple algorithm. in this example i get the elements whose indexes sum are two(module three) i wrote the method but the jcreator gives me "return statement is missing". how can i solve this.

```
public class hw1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] RaggedArray = {
                { "hello", "hi", "i", "nice", "good", "love" },
                { "what", "java", "there" }, 
                { "and", "cool", "door", "my" },
                { "time", "phone", "homework" }

        };
        System.out.println(hw_one(RaggedArray));
    }

    public static String hw_one(String[][] array) {
        String result;

        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {

                if ((row + column) % 3 == 2) {
                    result = array[row][column];
                }

            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: please format your code prior to posting. This is very hard to read.

Comment: y it was, i rly was in need to format it...

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how you can get a "`return` statement is missing" error when it clearly is not.

That said, my compiler complains that you're returning a potentially uninitialized variable (`result`). The following fixes the problem:

```
String result = null;
              ^^^^^^
```

Comment: yes you're right i'm sorry i am confused. and i applied your answer but the code gave me only one element.

Comment: never initialize a String with null, allways with nothing (""). this can not cause an NullPointer.The only0 excpetion is you want to check the result to be null or not

Comment: yepp i solved it eventually,thanks to all stackoverflow family :))

Comment: NPE wants NullPointerException it seems.

Answer (score 2):

you have to initialize the local varibale `result` before you use it. 
Initialize it to null or an empty string.

```
String result = null;  or  String result = "";
```